# Laravel 5.2 Authentication error: Accessing logged in page directly through URL

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I have Authenticate.php file in:

```
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware
```

I need to authenticate my user so that, the user can't access the logged in page by just writing it in URL. How to do it? 
When I searched, the solutions were for the Authenticate file which was in Middleware folder inside Http, which was a little different.

[image: This is my Authenticate.php and it's content]

Please tell me how to do it. I tried:

```
if(Auth::guard($guard) -> guest()){
if ($request -> ajax()){
return response['Unauthorized',401];
} else{
return redirect() -> guest('login'); 
}
}
return $next($request);
}
}
```

How to do it? please tell me options. Any suggestion is invited.
And, Thank you in advance... :)

Comment: What about just using middleware?

`Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/profile', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});`

Comment: It's not working. even after using it, I can access my login page just by writing "/dashboard" in URL, (dashboard is my next page)

Comment: Hmm. What about `['middleware' => ['web','auth']]`?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions you found while searching are correct, you should actually edit your middlewares inside `app/Http/Middleware` if you checked out the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate#authentication-routing), the right way to do it is:
You have to update this middleware `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` which has this function

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/admin');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

What you can do in your case, you can use the same if clause in your current handle function, so it looks like this:

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/admin');
}
if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response['Unauthorized',401];
} else {
        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }
}
return $next($request);
```

Comment: Thank you, actullyi got confused between Authenticate and RedirectIfAuthenticate,. But it is still not working.. i even changed the route to dashboard: Route::get('/dashboard',[
      'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
      'as'   => 'dashboard',
      'middleware' => 'guest'
     ]);

Comment: What is it exactly that is not working, can you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

Put all the routes that only the logged in users can access into `Auth` Middleware group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        // Routes here
});
```

Comment: it shows an error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::handle()

Comment: @shefalisharma for what purpose are you using Auth::handle()

Comment: I am not, I just used Auth()